# Saving user Input?

Tags: php, html, web

How do I save my user input to a simple .txt?

I am really new to php so please help me out here.

My code:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $data = $_POST['email'] . '-' . $_POST['password'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}

?>
```

Don't think I need to include this but I found a really cool looking login form and changed the names of course:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Material Login Form</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900|RobotoDraft:400,100,300,500,700,900'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>


<!-- Mixins-->
<!-- Pen Title-->
<div class="pen-title">
  <h1>Material Login Form</h1></div>
<div class="rerun"><a href="">Rerun Pen</a></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card">
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="Username" required="required"/>
        <label for="Username">Email</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input name="password" type="password" id="Password" required="required"/>
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button><span>Go</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="card alt">
    <div class="toggle"></div>
    <h1 class="title">Register
      <div class="close"></div>
    </h1>
    <form>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" id="Username" required="required"/>
        <label for="Username">Email</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="password" id="Password" required="required"/>
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="password" id="Repeat Password" required="required"/>
        <label for="Repeat Password">Repeat Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button><span>Next</span></button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Portfolio--><a id="portfolio" href="http://andytran.me/" title="View my portfolio!"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<!-- CodePen--><a id="codepen" href="http://codepen.io/andytran/" title="Follow me!"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>




  </body>
</html>
```

I'm at a loss here, I have no clue what to fix!

Comment: In which way it does not work? Your `<form>` tag does not contain any URL. So I suppose your JavaScript/jQuery code in js/index.js does register some submit handler, but it is not provided here. The PHP code looks okay. Also have look into the JavaScript console/error reporting of your browser.

Comment: It doesn't create ANY file.txt or any file at all. It returns blank without an error. EDIT: How to I check the console? Sorry I am pretty new.

Comment: Put an `echo 'anything';` in your code to see if its called at all. If you can see that, it is most likely a problem with user rights.

Comment: Also include `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: It returns back and I can see it just fine EDIT: Ok adding error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: It doesn't even return an error ._.

Comment: Maybe you are running into [open_basedir restrictions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). Can you call `phpinfo();` somewhere and check for that? Or safe mode, if you are running a very old PHP version.

Comment: I'm using a free hosting provider. x10hosting to be honest.

Comment: Possibly errors are not displayed, you can change this behaviour with `ini_set('display_errors', stdout);`.

Comment: You got there a webspace or a virtual machine?

Comment: This is all in the cloud.

Comment: I'd suppose that you are not allowed to write to `/tmp/`, if this is on a shared machine (virtual or not). You may have more luck if you set the permission of the scripts directory to 0777 (make it accessible to any user) and remove the `/tmp/`. Of course that should only temporary set this way, because then the mydata.txt is available over the website. Easier and more secure solution would be to use a database, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

***something like this:***

```
    $content = $_POST['email'];
    $myfile = fopen("".$name.".txt", "w") or die("error"); // make txt file
    fwrite($myfile, $content); // write some content
    fclose($myfile); // save and close
```

Comment: Thats just a more complicated and less distinct way to write `$ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);` (fourth line of code of OP).

Answer (score 1):

```
      <div class="pen-title">
                <h1>Material Login Form</h1></div>
            <div class="rerun"><a href="">Rerun Pen</a></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card"></div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
                    <form action="upload.php" method="post">
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input name="email" type="text" id="Username" 
             required="required"/>
                            <label for="Username">Email</label>
                            <div class="bar"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input name="password" type="password"  
           id="Password" required="required"/>
                            <label for="Password">Password</label>
                            <div class="bar"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button-container">
                            <button type="submit">Go</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer"><a href="#">Forgot your password? 
             </a></div>
                    </form>
                </div>            
            </div>   

//in php file use this code for saving file
$myfile= fopen('/tmp/mydata.txt','w') or die("Unable to open file!");;
fwrite($myfile,$_POST);//or $data
```